# fullCalendar timeformat customizing

Tags: fullcalendar, time-format

I'm trying to customize the timeformat of FullCalendar by schedule type.

I want to set the date value (instead of time value) in case of allDay schedule, and set the time value in time schedule, respectively, in the same agenda view.
In other words, I want to do something like,

$('#calendar').fullCalendar(

```
              timeFormat: {
                     allDay: 'mm-dd',
                     timeSchedule(not allDay):'HH:MM'
                           }
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I manipulated the title for specific events inside the eventRender like so:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
  if(event.allDay) {
    timeformat = event.start.format('your format') + ' - ' event.end.format('your format');
    element.find('.fc-title').html(timeformat + ' ' + event.title);
  }
}
```